# Text align doesnt work with span

Tags: css, css-float, less

I need the below alignment.I can achieve this using table but I want a solution without using a table.

```
  Sub Total  $596.00
   Shipping  $35.00
        Tax  $63.11
Order Total  $694.11
```

When i dont use a table it looks like below even though i use text-align:right for the first span element.

```
Sub Total    $596.00
Shipping     $35.00
Tax          $63.11
Order Total  $694.11
```

Comment: Why not use a table? This looks like a good candidate for the `<table>` element.

Comment: use `text-align:right` for all `td`, **or** make a css rule for it.

Comment: I cant add table header content. Without which the accessibility tool pops error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `inline-block` and `first-child` to `align` and add `padding`.

Something like this:

```css
#container > div > div {
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:75px;
}

#container > div > div:first-child {
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <div>Sub Total</div>
        <div>$596.00</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Shipping</div>
        <div>$35.00</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Tax</div>
        <div>$63.11</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Order Total</div>
        <div>$694.11</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

text-align doesn't work with inline elements. Try to set display:inline-block or display:block to the span element.